# How to select the previous element using jquery "on"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I am trying to edit the text on a `label`.
I want to:

1. Show a label and hidden text Box.
2. On click of label: label gets hide and text Box shows where I can edit text.
3. On Enter, text Box should hide and label should display the entered text.

Here is the sample code.
But its not working as expected.

```
<h4>Editable labels (below)</h4>
<span class="k-link">
<label class="pull-left">Dashboard</label>
<input class="clickedit" type="text" id="731"/>
</span>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh7zosdc)**

Comment: Use `contenteditable` attribute could be a good approach for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/sh7zosdc/1/).

Change the code from

```
 $('.k-link').on('click', ".clickedit.prev()", function (event) {..
```

into

```
 $('.k-link').on('click', ".pull-left", function (event) {..
```

And add inline css style for

```
 <input class="clickedit" type="text" id="731" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. However when I run this code in my application, I get a javascript error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: hide is not defined". But in fiddle it seems to be working. Can you help me about this issue?

Comment: Can you please tell me what line of error you got that same with fiddle code?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the functionality you want?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#label', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.hide();
  $('#731').removeClass('hidden');
});
$(document).on('focusout', '#731', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var val = that.val();
  that.hide();
  $('#label').after('<span>' + val + '</span>');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Editable labels (below)</h4>
<span class="k-link">
<label id="label" class="pull-left">Dashboard</label>
<input class="clickedit hidden" type="text" id="731"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".clickedit").hide()

    $(".pull-left").on("click", function(){
        $(this).hide()
        $(".clickedit").show()
    });

    $(".clickedit").on("blur", function(){
        $(this).hide()
        $(".pull-left").text($(this).val()).show()
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working check it 
i have just edit the selector it was .clickedit.prev() and i have change it to .pull-left

```
    $('.k-link').on('click', ".pull-left", function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show().focus();
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anisboukhris/qho0uLzv/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. However when I run this code in my application, I get a javascript error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: hide is not defined". But in fiddle it seems to be working. Can you help me about this issue?

Comment: try to set the last version of jquery maybe 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

may be try this:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#f1").hide();
$("#text").hide();
var $curr = $( "#start" );
$curr.css( "background", "#f99" );
$( "button" ).on('click',function() {

  $curr = $curr.prev();// this will go to previous div as you have asked how to get previous element.
  $curr.show();
});
$( "#label" ).on('click',function() {
 $("#label").hide();
 $("#text").show();
 $( "#text" ).blur(function() {
  $("#label").show();
  $("#text").hide();
  $("#label").html($("#text").val());
 });

});

  });
```

```css
 div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px blue solid;
    padding: 2px;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f1"><span id="label">Came to previous div</span><input type="text" id="text" /></div>

<div id="start"></div>

<p><button>Go to Prev</button></p>
```